# Reading data from Firebase returns an empty class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm saving objects of this class in the Firebase:

```
public class Route {
    private String uniqueId;
    private long routeTime;
    private float distance;
    private List<Double> lat;
    private List<Double> lon;

    public Route(){}

    public Route (Route r){
        this.uniqueId = r.uniqueId;
        this.routeTime = r.routeTime;
        this.distance = r.distance;
        this.lat = r.lat;
        this.lon = r.lon;
    }

    public Route (String id ,long time, float distance, List<Double> lat,List<Double> lon){
        this.uniqueId=id;
        this.routeTime=time;
        this.distance=distance;
        this.lat=lat;
        this.lon=lon;
    }

    public String getUid(){
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public long getTime(){
        return routeTime;
    }

    public float getDist(){
        return distance;
    }

    public List<Location> getPoints(){
        List<Location> points = new ArrayList<Location>();
        for (int i=0 ;i < this.lon.size() ;i++){
            Location temp = new Location("");
            temp.setLongitude(this.lon.get(i));
            temp.setLatitude(this.lat.get(i));
            points.add(temp);
        }
        return points;
    }

}
```

This is an example of the database after the upload:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaNmo.png

Here is the path I used to save it the database:

```
Routes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Routes");

currUserRoutes = Routes.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
currRoute = currUserRoutes.push();
routeUID = currRoute.getKey();
Route temp = new Route(routeUID,(endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime())/1000,distance,lat,lon);
        currRoute.setValue(temp); //currRoute is a database reference
```

And here is how I'm trying to retrieve it:

```
DatabaseReference routeRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Routes").child(userID);
Query a=routeRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(routeID);
a.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             curr_route = singleSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
        }
    }
```

When I'm debugging android studio shows the correct values when retrieving the data. what I mean is this: [pressMe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuGfn.png)

The green text contain the correct values that I expect but the values I get in curr_route are null as if he got through the default constructor [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wBCU.png).

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to name your Java variables the exact same way you save them in your database so the mapping that the Firebase SDK does is simple. Ensure the getter and setters as well are standard convention e.g change `lat` to `latitude` and the getter to `getLatitude()` and setter to `setLatitude()` **You must have getters and setters**
2. I noticed your `latitude` and `longitude` Java variables are saved as `List<Double>` even though your data is simply a `double/float`. This could be potentially problematic.

Comment: Thanks! that helped!

Comment: Glad you fixed it!! If it helped kindly upvote or accept the answer so that others may know it is of value

Comment: I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation yet but I listed it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Route object should have both getter *and* setter methods for each of the properties it wants to expose.  Right now you just have a handful of getters, but you'll need setters in order for the Realtime Database SDK to be able to populate those values when reading from a database snapshot with `getValue(Route.class)`.